# Create oracle trigger that applies 15% discount to rnk = 1

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, database, discount

I'm having trouble writing an sql statement to create a trigger that applies a 15% discount to any future purchases made by top client. it would apply a 15% reduction to the pruchase amount whenever a new purchase made by that top client is inserted into the purchase table. So would i add a trigger after inserting a new purchase? I have been reading through a couple guides/tutorials but would like some help/guidance. thanks

```
SELECT CLIENTNO, CNAME, SPA PURCHASE_AMOUNT
FROM (SELECT CLIENT.CLIENTNO, CLIENT.CNAME, SUM(PURCHASE.AMOUNT) SPA,  RANK() OVER (ORDER        BY SUM(PURCHASE.AMOUNT) DESC) RNK
FROM PURCHASE JOIN CLIENT ON PURCHASE.CLIENTNO = CLIENT.CLIENTNO
GROUP BY CLIENT.CLIENTNO, CLIENT.CNAME)
WHERE RNK = 1;
```

Comment: How do you propose to prevent this trigger from re-applying the discount every time it runs?  The select clause as written could easily find the same client over and over.

Comment: This is not a task suited to implementation with a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a better solution might be to have a DISCOUNTS table which the trigger populates/updates with a value of 15% (or 0.15 or 0.85). The sales price look-up routine would then take this into account when making a sale. (This might also simplify the process of, say, a 10% off day.)